# Hardcoding email into Mailable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I have a members website and I need to send out 2 email upon user registration.

1. Welcome email to new user (This is fine)
2. Notice email to admin notifying them of the new user.(**Need Help**)

I'm using Events and Listeners to do this. I can currently send both emails to the new registered user so I believe my issue is with the `Mail::to function`

Here is what is currently working, but it's sending to the new registered user.

I need it to go to admin@mysite.com. How can I hardcode in that email, or grab the user with admin privileges from my users table?

Could I do something like this:

```
Mail::to($event->user->username('admin')->email)->send(new NewUserCreated($event->user));
```

The above gives me an error:  `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::username()`

**Listener:** *SendNewUserCreated.php*

```
public function handle(NewUser $event)
{
    Mail::to($event->user->email)->send(new NewUserCreated($event->user));
}
```

**Mail:** *NewUserCreated.php*

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Custom Subject Here')->markdown('emails.staff.newusercreated');
}
```

**Mail Blade:** *newusercreated.blade.php*

```
@component('mail::message')
# A new user has registered on Website.

Please check that the following credentials match your records.

@component('mail::panel')
- **User Name:** {{$user->username}}
- **Full Name:** {{$user->first_name}} {{$user->last_name}}
- **Email:** {{$user->email}}
- **4 Digit Pin:** {{$user->pin}}
- **Street:** {{$user->street}}
- **City:** {{$user->city}}
- **State:** {{$user->state}}
- **Zip:** {{$user->zip}}
@endcomponent

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'http://wesite.oo/admin'])
Grant Access
@endcomponent


Thank You,<br>
*{{ config('app.name') }}, Notifier*
@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your table is set up but something like this:

```
User::where('username', 'admin')->first()->email;
User::where('is_admin', 1)->first()->email;
```

Or use a config or environment variable:

```
config('myapp.admin_email');
env('ADMIN_EMAIL');
```

Comment: Would `User::where('username', 'admin')->first()->email;` Replace the `Mail::to($event->user->email)->send(new NewUserCreated($event->user));`  in the Listener?

Comment: Thank you. This worked! `Mail::to(User::where('username', 'admin')->first()->email)->send(new NewUserCreated($event->user));` Also needed to make sure to add class `use App\User;`